# I can't create server in pgadmin4 (http://127.0.0.1:5050/browser/) on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pgadmin

[image: Error]

I installed pgadmin4 for my Ubuntu 16.10 and run it on http://127.0.0.1:5050/browser/ but it just have sever group. I create sever but it alert like in picture.

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "htphuocdl-desktop" (127.0.1.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Answer (score 0):

## Create server:

- Please configure host name/address:127.0.0.1 with default IP or custom IP address, Incase if you used custom IP in your application provide proper IP address while configure.

#### Add following code in your config_local.py

```
import os
DATA_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(u'~/.pgadmin/')) 
LOG_FILE = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgadmin4.log') 
SQLITE_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgadmin4.db') 
SESSION_DB_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'sessions') 
STORAGE_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'storage')
SERVER_MODE = True
#Please provide default IP or custom IP address
DEFAULT_SERVER='127.0.0.1'
```